# How to access EntityManagerFactory from EntityManager in Eclipselink

Tags: java, caching, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I'm using Eclipselink JPA(2.0).I need to access entityManagerFactory to clear all cache since normal property settings or refresh or setting hints didn't work for me. I have found a way to do it from this piece of code:

```
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
```

But there is no such method called getEntityManagerFactory() in eclipselink entityManager. How can i do it?

I'm using Spring bean configuration for EntityManagerFactory and entityManager is annotated with @PersistenceContext in DAO layer.

In Spring beans config:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
<property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyService" />
</bean>
```

In DAO:

```
private EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The JPA 2 vendor has nothing to do with the availability of the methods you listed, as they all use the same interfaces. Please post relevant code so we can diagnose the real problem.

Comment: Edited with source code, please check it.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? Keep in mind that you should be using version 3.0 if you want good JPA 2 support.

Answer (score 1):

If using JPA1 then you can't using standard JPA API since that method didn't exist then.
If using JPA2 then EM.getEntityManagerFactory() is the way since it was added there.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getEntityManagerFactory()

Comment: I'm using eclipselink 2.2.0 version, it implements JPA 2.0, right?